# Significance of !! logical expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logical-operators

Maybe I am too quick in asking this question , but I was going through angular code and I found the logical expression evaluation like this : 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/attrs.js#L362

Essentially an attribute was evaluated like :

> attr.$set(attrName, !!value);

Is there a particular reason why was this done this way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!!` is a concise way of ensuring that `value` will be a boolean.